# Progress doesn't displayed on ProgressBar

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Progress according to ***android:progress="60"*** doesnt displayed

[image]

Progressbar in *activity_main.xml*

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/circle"
    style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="172dp"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:progress="60"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/gButton"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.323"
    tools:layout_constrainedWidth="true" />
```

***id*** and ***progressdrawable*** have a ***circle*** value, since At first I tried to make a round progress bar, but there was the same situation *(despite **android:progress="60"** it appears as if the progressbar is 100)*

shape.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:useLevel="false"
    >

    <gradient android:useLevel="false"
        android:endColor="#6be400"
        android:centerColor="#008500"
        android:startColor="#6be400"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an easy fix: use `android:background` and not `android:progressDrawable`.

Add this and remove your attributes `android:progressDrawable` and `style`:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"

android:background="@drawable/shape"
android:progressTint="someColor"
android:progressBackgroundTint="#0000"
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: It seems no(
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"

Comment: I do not know if this decision is correct in my case, because my api 17, and for `android:progressTint="someColor"` and 
`android:progressBackgroundTint="#0000"` need api 21 and higher, but I think that the decision is correct. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
android:indeterminate="false"
android:max="100"
```

Progress is calculated as a fraction of the max value and you are trying to create a determinate progressBar

Comment: Both of these are default values.